# Laravel 5 make routing with unique parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am currently using a route with a parameter `name`to query the profile of a user in my application.

So for example: `/members/john`will show the profile of John.

You see the problem here, if there are 2 John's then it's gonna be a problem.

I know I could do something like this `/members/id`since id is unique but I want the url to look pretty with the user's name and not a random number.

So my question is if there is a way to use the id to make it unique but to display the name in url?

my route:

```
Route::get('/members/{name}', 'UserController@usersProfile');
```

My usersProfile method:

```
/**
 * Returns a users profile.
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function usersProfile($name)
{
    $profile = $this->userService->getProfile($name);

    if ($profile == null) {
        return redirect('members')->with('status', 'Whoops, looks like that member does not exist (yet).');
    }

    return view('members/profile', ['profile' => $profile]);
}
```

Comment: Create a unique username for each user and use that value in route

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thanks for your response, but I don't want to use unique usernames.

Comment: also depends upon the idea .... is anyone ever actually going to type out a URL ... if you think so then this naming stuff matters, if not then it doesn't matter  `{id}/{name}`  now there can't be a collision and name is still in the URL

Comment: You also don't want to use id then how you can determine user ?

Comment: In the migration of your users table ensure the `name` field is unique `$table->string('name')->unique();`

Comment: @yvesdaxmaz I don't think that's a good idea since there is a possibility that there will be users with the same name.

Comment: @lagbox Yeah I know I can do it that way with the id in the url but I don't think it's pretty but if there is no better way i'll have to do it

Comment: because there isn't a way to get the user with the `name` maybe there will be many user with the same name, you can just add the `username` field that will make things easy because you will specified that the username is unique

Comment: how could there be another way ... how are you going to resolve naming collisions?

Comment: @lagbox I was wondering if there might be a way in Laravel to use a hidden parameter or something. Like maybe I could define a route `/members/{id}` and use the id to query the user but display a route like this: `members/name``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use some package for slug your model name :

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable

https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

these packages automatically doing that for you.

if you have same name this will happen:

```
http://example.com/post/my-dinner-with-andre-francois
http://example.com/post/my-dinner-with-andre-francois-1
http://example.com/post/my-dinner-with-andre-francois-2
```

just in production i have some issue with scopes...
when you apply global scope on model , it may create duplicate slug for that ... you can fix that by add this to your model :

```
public function scopeFindSimilarSlugs(Builder $query, Model $model, $attribute, $config, $slug)
    {
        $separator = $config['separator'];

        return $query->withoutGlobalScopes()->where(function (Builder $q) use ($attribute, $slug, $separator) {
            $q->where($attribute, '=', $slug)
                ->orWhere($attribute, 'LIKE', $slug . $separator . '%');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Cool packages, exactly what I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add another column to your user table with name 'slug' or 'username' and map that column in your route.

In your users model, make a static function to generate unique slug with a number attached and save it in that new column to provide users with public/private profile URLs.

This below sample will stop returning slug/username after 100 users with the same name.

```
public static function getUniqueSlug($name) {
  $original_slug = getSlug($name); // Default getter to get value in model
  $slug = str_slug($original_slug); //Convert a string into url friendly string with hyphens

  while(true) {
    $count = User::where('slug', $slug)->count();
    if($count > 0) {
      $slug = $original_slug."-".rand(1,99);
    } else {
      return $slug;
    }
  }
}
```